# Getting Error - PG::UndefinedColumn (ERROR: column d.adsrc does not exist on heroku with postgres version 13.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting below error while running my Rails application on Heroku

```
WARN -- : [6a47e5ee-5dd5-452b-80c1-3b7c4fd6b528] Failed to submit event: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column d.adsrc does not exist
2021-07-08T07:59:39.814486+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS sql_type, d.adsrc AS...
2021-07-08T07:59:39.814487+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2021-07-08T07:59:39.814488+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-08T07:59:39.815559+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-07-08T07:59:39.815471 #4] FATAL -- : [6a47e5ee-5dd5-452b-80c1-3b7c4fd6b528]   
2021-07-08T07:59:39.815561+00:00 app[web.1]: [6a47e5ee-5dd5-452b-80c1-3b7c4fd6b528] PG::UndefinedColumn (ERROR:  column d.adsrc does not exist
2021-07-08T07:59:39.815561+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS sql_type, d.adsrc AS...
2021-07-08T07:59:39.815562+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
```

As per search, I get that this is happening with Postgres 12 but I am getting the same issue on Postgres 13.3 on Heroku

With the same Postgres version on local, it works fine, so might be something with Heroku but I am not getting what it is, help, please !!

Answer (score 1):

`adsrc` was removed in Postgres version 12 see here [12 Release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html).  I'm guessing that in your local situation you are connecting to database version 11 or less.

Comment: Nope, I have 13.3 on local, and on Heroku also it's 13.3. Curious to find out the solution, need to find out what Heroku does at their side.

Comment: Check your self there is no `pg_attrdef.adsrc` column in version 13. You will need to find out what query is looking for it on the Heroku side of things.